# Login automation and crawling using Scrapy Python

Tags: python, scrapy

I have been trying to write a script to retrieve my accepted solutions on spoj [See more](http://www.spoj.com/users/codegagu/)

I got stuck in automating the login process. I found Scrapy difficult to understand. After going through the docs and the code samples many times I got a vague picture of what happens behind the scene and this is where I stand now:

(I have commented the code at required places)

```
import os
import os.path
import scrapy
import urllib.request
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from scrapy.http import Request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

class LoginSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'spoj'
    start_urls = ['http://www.spoj.com/login']
    outputFile = open('output.txt' , 'w')

    def parse(self, response):
        username = input('Enter username\n')
        password = input('Enter password\n')
        return scrapy.FormRequest.from_response(
            response,
            formdata={'username': username, 'password': password},
            callback=self.after_login
        )

    def after_login(self, response):

        # Even if I type in correct username and password it always leads to 
        # authentication faliure and the following if statement evaluates to true.

        if str.encode('Authentication failed!') in response.body:
            self.logger.error("Login failed")
            print ('Incorrect credentials')
            return    

        print('lol') # ofcourse this isn't printed
        return scrapy.Request(url = "http://www.spoj.com/myaccount/" , callback = self.retrieve_codes ) 

    # needless to say, the following function is never called
    def retrieve_codes(self, response):

        print('Hello testing!') 
        url = 'http://www.spoj.com/files/src/16731976/'
        html = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html , 'html.parser')
        self.outputFile.write(str(soup.prettify()))
```

In the docs it was `if "authentication failed" in response.body:` which I changed to

`if str.encode('Authentication failed!') in response.body:` reasons being

- I was getting this error `a byte like object is required not 'str'`
- In spoj on entering wrong credentials `Authentication failed!` is displayed and not `authentication failed`. We need to be precise here.

Please tell me where I'm doing wrong. I haven't found any good resources on the net that discusses the form validation thing in detail. After seeing [this code from docs](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#using-formrequest-from-response-to-simulate-a-user-login) my initial questions were,

- Is this the only way to do it?
- Will this method work for every website? Because I learnt that complexity of this process varies from site to site.
- Can I find an even more descriptive explanation of what is happening behind?

I have also tried using robobrowser but in vain. 
I was kind of expecting a good documentation like that of beautiful soup.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the wrong `formdata` field names. You need to adjust the example code from the scrapy docs to the specific website. Currently you use `username` and `password` as `formdata` fields.

If you use the developer tools of your browser while logging in you can see that the fields that are sent by `POST` are labeled `login_user` and `password`.

So this should be easy to fix :-)

Comment: thanks! :) I didn't know that the value of 'name' attribute is used in form data. My shameful ignorance